# How to include 'edit-config' tag of Cordova configuration in Meteor?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

Meteor uses [`mobile-config.js`](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#using-plugins)to create Cordova's `config.xml` automatically. Since iOS 10, developers must include respective reasons when they will access to Microphone, Camera, Contacts, etc. in the `Info.plist`file which is modified by Cordova itself in Cordova builds.

I need to include the following in the Cordova's [`config.xml`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config)to request access to device Microphone.

```
<edit-config target="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need microphone access to record sounds</string>
</edit-config>
```

How is `edit-config` tag maintained by using Meteor [`mobile-config.js`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. The following should be added to the `mobile-config.js`.

```
App.appendToConfig(`
  <edit-config target="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>Need microphone access to record voice</string>
  </edit-config>
`);
```

In case you will need there is more information in the official [documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#system-permissions) about configuring plug-ins in Meteor.